# Pending Paid Apps Agreement

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore, development, app-store-connect, developer-program

**TLDR**

Did you ever experienced long verification time when submitting paid apps agreement?

I'm waiting one month for comparing my ID card agains name on submitted contract.

**Long story**

I've submitted the agreement and did the verification and got back email that Apple needs more info and same form appeared again. That happened four times.

I've noticed my company name was missing few characters and Apple Support fixed it for me.

Did the submission again and now I'm waiting 3 weeks. I've contacted Apple Developer Support many many times (like 10 calls, number of emails and bunch of screenshot of AppStore Connect).

They told me to have patience. Not providing any deadline when they will fix it. I've contacted now three senior Support members. Still no action from their end even though I believe they've did a lot of work. They marked the issue as high priority and escalated the case three times already.

Customers are waiting for the app and both me and Apple are losing money (given their service fee). Since I've paid the high price every year on their Apple Developer program I feel I'm not getting the value of my money.

I took a (and maybe silly) leap and sent email to Tim Cook and Phil Schiller in order to get App up and running.

I'm reaching the end of my patience and I still think waiting one month is a good amount of patience. App is marked "ready for sale" and AppStore page is still empty.

I don't know what to do now. It seems I'm at the end of possible resolution.

Did you ever experienced this issue? Do you have any ideas how to escalate such case in order to be resolved? I'm desperately looking for any help of any kind.

Huge thanks for reading this!